Identify a sci-fi movie about humanoid aliens who want to terraform earth
I remember this movie, where race of aliens was trying to terraform earth as they could not easily life on our planet. There was that particular scene that I remember very well. It was some sort of hangar/factory building with some special machines/inhalators that allow aliens to breathe. Movie protagonist somehow ended in this warehouse and to stay hidden he also inhaled something, the scene ends with the main hero entering the bus/train with other aliens.
I also remember that there were some yellow lights, or the whole scene was in yellow/orange tones. Also, I think that the aliens had to inhale methane, or sulfur? but not 100% sure:/
This scene and movie is bothering me for months now, I checked movies like: the arrival, they live, body snatchers and Alien Nation. no lucky...
Anyone know the name of this movie?

I don't see The Invaders, (1995), starring Scott Bakula, in your list.  From the movie's message board:

Bakula ends up on the inaugural ride of a Los Angeles subway train
  with a political candidate who is big on ecology. The aliens want to
  knock off the candidate (who some think is destined for the White
  House). The aliens have screwed around with sensors in the subway
  ventilation system with the intention of starting a methane explosion.
  The formerly good cop, who has been "probed" by the English-accented
  female doctor (an alien) tries to take over the train, but Bakula has
  sneaked on to the train as a maintenance guy and eventually overtakes
  the cop and manages to stop the train with the help of a supervisor in
  the subway dispatch center.


Yes! that's the movie I was looking for! Great job Will! Thanks a lot!
